# Voice tasks from siri running on some lang in windows

Tags: ios, windows, siri

I'm tried research about, but don't founded something concrete about that;

Is there a way to make the SIRI communicate with windows, with node or something else? i'll be try make voice commands to change the rgb of my pc using SIRI, OpenRGBSdk and a land that can make this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.